# Using Certain React-Bootstrap Components Causes Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I just upgraded to React Bootstrap v. 0.27.1, React v. 0.14.0 and React Router v. 1.0.0-rc3 and now I'm getting an **Invariant Violation** when I use certain React Bootstrap components.

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://fb.me/react-refs-must-have-owner).

Specifically I see this when I use the `<Input>` and `<Nav>` components. So I get the following behaviour.

```html
// Does NOT work.
// --------------
<Navbar>
    <Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={1}>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/">Home</NavItem>
    </Nav>
</Navbar>

// Works
// -----
<Navbar>
    <ul className="nav nav-pills">
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/">Home</NavItem>
    </ul>
</Navbar>
```

As you can see, switching `<Nav>` to its regular Bootstrap markup fixes the issue. Same when I add an `<Input>` component. There might be other components that cause things to break, but I have only narrowed it down to these two.

In any case, I cannot figure out why this happens with these components and not with others and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened [this issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1402) in the react-bootstrap repo and someone pointed out that this is not React Bootstrap specific, but that it was caused because two copies of React were being loaded. It seems that Browserify was causing this as I was able to resolve this by adding [browserify-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-resolutions) to my build process. Since I use Gulp, my gulpfile ended up including the two tasks below. Note that browserify-resolutions is called with the `.plugin(resolutions, 'react')` line.

```js
// Compile third-party dependencies separately for faster performance.
gulp.task('browserify-vendor', function() {
    return browserify()
        .require(dependencies)
        .plugin(resolutions, 'react')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('vendor.bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(production, streamify(uglify({ mangle: false }))))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

// Compile only project files, excluding all third-party dependencies.
gulp.task('browserify', ['browserify-vendor'], function() {
    return browserify('src/app.js')
        .external(dependencies)
        .plugin(resolutions, 'react')
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(production, streamify(uglify({ mangle: false }))))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting Juan. I did try browserify-resolutions but it totally refused to de-dupe the two copies of React in the bundles. In the end I fixed the problem by removing my entire node_modules folder and doing a full npm re-install.

This had the effect of removing the React 0.14.0 included dependency underneath react-dom (which was causing the duplication on build). I am wondering whether that may have been down to the latest NPM using a flattened folder structure which automatically de-dupes in the hierarchy.

After this I had no problems and didn't need to use browserify-resolutions at all.

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you land here looking for a solution and nothing is working. AND IF you also are using create-react-app then I suggest you check your index.html file for multiple "built" bundles which IS loading multiple `react` or whatever that is causing the `Invariant Violation` error. Hope it helps someone.